# Best way to handle object's fields validation => Either / Try (scala 2.10) / ValidationNEL (scalaz)

Tags: scala, exception, builder-pattern, scalaz7

Let's assume an object constructed using a builder pattern.

This builder pattern would contain a `build` method focusing on fields validation and then on conversion to the targeted type.

This validation could be implemented using:

- `Either[FailureObject, TargetObject]` type
- `Try[TargetObject]` (new feature from Scala 2.10)
- `Validation[FailureObject, TargetObject]` or `ValidationNEL[FailureObject, TargetObject]` from scalaz library

I read that one of the main advantages of `Validation` over `Either` type is that `Validation` can accumulate failures "out of the box".

But what about the "new" `Try` way? I noticed that `Try` has "monadic" methods out of the box also, like `map`, `flatMap` etc... what was really missing with Either type without help of `Projection`.

Thus, I'd imagine each field validation method returning a `Try[FieldType]` and more precisely, in case of any failure, a `Try[SpecificFieldExceptionType]`; this nested one containing a `String` message field and a rootCause field that could be accumulated throughout the `build` method.

Using Scala 2.10, could or should `Try` practice replace scalaz validation library for simple validation like builder pattern involves?

**EDIT ******

By reading `Try` source code, it sounds that `Try` can't accumulate several exceptions and thus is oriented fail-fast.
Even `Try.flatMap`returns the potentential previous failure and so doesn't have the notion of accumulation:

```
def flatMap[U](f: T => Try[U]): Try[U] = this.asInstanceOf[Try[U]]
```

On the contrary of `ValidationNEL` that handles accumulation feature.

Any confirmation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are tradeoffs:

- `scalaz.Validation` is able to accumulate errors of type `E` given a `Semigroup[E]` instance. It's intended for use as an `Applicative`, like:

  ```
  (fragileFoo |@| fragileBar) { case (foo, bar) => doSomething(foo, bar) }
  ```

  It does have `map` and `flatMap` methods, biased towards the `Success` side, so you can use it conveniently in a `for`-comprehension. However, there is no `Monad` instance defined for it, so it can't be used in any higher-order stuff (for example, you can't use it with monad transformers). This shortcoming doesn't seem like it would be a problem for you, though.
- `scalaz.\/`, which you didn't mention, does form a `Monad` (again, biased toward the `Right` side). But when used as an `Applicative`, it doesn't accumulate failures as `Validation` does.
- `util.Try` is similar to `scalaz.\/`, specialized to `Throwable`. Although it again lacks accumulation of errors, it does have the notion of error recovery. However, for your "builder pattern" use case, it seems like this might not be terribly useful.
- Finally, `util.Either` isn't worth considering, compared to the other three options: because it's not biased toward one side or the other, you have to explicitly and consistently ask for the `left` or `right` projection every time you want to do something monadic.

My best guess is that for your situation, `scalaz.Validation` is the most appropriate choice.

Comment: Couldn't imagine a better answer => very well-explained ! Thanks a lot :) Indeed, I chose Validation to work with my Builder.